# MVVM Unique column in DataGrid <-> ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My apologies if this question has been answered already. I've been struggling to figure out how to implement this and Google/StackOverflow searches haven't given me an answer that fits my needs. 
To provide context to stuff like BindableBase -> I'm using Prism WPF 7.1

Model:

```
public class SampleModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _id;
    public string ID
    {
        get => _id;
        set => SetProperty(ref _id, value);
    }

    public string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }

    public SampleModel()
    {
        ID = string.Empty;
        Name = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SampleModel> Collection { get; set; }

    public SampleModel SelectedEntry { get; set; }        

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<SampleModel>();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntry}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                        Header="ID"
                        Width="*"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                        Header="Name"
                        Width="*"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I would like to ensure that the [cells of the WPF DataGrid goes red if the ID isn't unique.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXgD3.png)

The only solution I can think right now would be to add a pointer to the `Collection<SampleModel>` to every `SampleModel` instance, have `SampleModel` implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo`, and iterate looking for duplicate during `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.TryValidateProperty()` (using a custom `UniqueAttribute`). However I'm worried that this wouldn't be the right solution since the Model would be coupled to the Collection that contains it.

```
public class UniqueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Validate that property does not exist in collection?
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a better way of implementing this?

Comment: This comment might not appear to be an answer to your question, but if you think about it deeply then it is... Why exactly are you showing an ID column in your grid, especially one that must be unique (and therefore would have a propensity to be gibberish to an end user)? Does it serve any purpose outside of your application? Can the user copy that ID and insert it somewhere else to get a result? If not then hide it and generate it....

Comment: ....checking a value for validation on every key stroke is expensive, and prone to error - what happens when you have too many records to have them all loaded at once? You **can** do it, but just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I forgot to mention. The user will be inserting the unique ID, I can't generate it. I don't necessarily have to check on every key stroke, I can probably perform the validation upon a datagrid commit.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have used ID in this example program.

Comment: Agreed, having that as an ID column isn't optimal. However you still have the uniqueness use case which can still be tricky because you don't necessarily have all the records to hand that need to be checked. Normally you could [use a validation rule](http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2011/07/taking-databinding-validation-and-mvvm.html) but something like this might require a different approach, such as validating the value after the row is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way to enforce uniqueness is to let the database do it. ID sounds like the primary key of your table, so the database will throw an exception if you try to create a duplicate. Catch the error and turn it into a user friendly validation message.

If you rely on your UI, you run the risk of two users creating the same ID.